# Unresolved reference: FragmentDirections

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

i have this problem, i already put in me build.gradle the versions and the plugins of 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
i resync the proyect, clean it and rebuild. but the FragmentDirections still no working.

My ListAdapter.kt:

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

    class ComercioListAdapter(private val comercios: List<Comercio>) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<ComercioListAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    
        class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
            val nombreTextView: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.textNombre)
            val descripcionTextView: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.textDireccion)
            val telefonoTextView: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.textTelefono)
           // val imageView: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView)
        }
    
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.item_comercio, parent, false)
            return ViewHolder(view)
        }
    
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
            val comercio = comercios[position]
            holder.nombreTextView.text = comercio.nombre
            holder.descripcionTextView.text = comercio.direccion
            holder.descripcionTextView.text = comercio.telefono
         //   holder.imageView.setImageResource(comercio.imagen)
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
                // Se hace clic en la miniatura del comercio
                val action = CategoriesFragmentDirections.actionCategoriesFragmentToComercio(comercio)
                holder.itemView.findNavController().navigate(action)
            }
        }
    
        override fun getItemCount() = comercios.size
    }
```

[image]
My build.gradle (module)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'// add here.

}
```

My build.gradle (project)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        def nav_version = "2.5.3"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'  version '2.5.3' apply false
}
```

Note:
already use in the build.gradle (project) this line

```
id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'  version '2.5.3' apply false
```

but with the same result, and when i try put this in the build.gradle (modelu) give me an error when try to sync:

```
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
```

mobile_navigation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/nav_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:name="com.developmentsls.valenciaappguide.English.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_categories"
        android:name="com.developmentsls.valenciaappguide.English.ui.categories.CategoriesFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_categories"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_categories" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_contact"
        android:name="com.developmentsls.valenciaappguide.English.ui.contact.ContactFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_contact"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_contact" />
</navigation>
```

Comment: This would indicate you don't have an action defined in your nav graph xml file. What does your navigation xml file look like?

Comment: @dominicoder i dont have nav_graph.xml, i only have mobile_navigation.xml (updated in the question) that was created automatically by the idle, i remmenber that many years ago with bundle its was different, im feeling like starting from 0. So i will need the nav_graph.xml? how can i implement that? because my fragment layout its already loaded correctly. The main issue its when i try to add another fragment to excecute when i click on an item in the recycleview on the fragment layout.

Comment: That's fine, the name doesn't matter. That's the file. And, as expected, you don't define an `action` to actually navigate from one fragment to another. Have you read through the documentation on using the Navigation Library? https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started